# Dropdown menu - links dim when selected (Safari Only)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

having a frustrating time trying to solve this.  I have a dropdown menu in my Navbar and when it's selected the other links dim significantly, only in Safari (looks fine in Chrome and Firefox).   I went back to the original and unmodified BootStrap 3.3 Template (Sticky footer with fixed navbar) and the issue is present.  Might there be a work around is CSS for this.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.   link to site is http://www.futureyouthrecords.org/indexalt.html

Comment: Use the vendor-prefixed property `-webkit` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Izzy.  Adding -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; in the CSS Body stopped the dimming effect!  Oddly though Safari still displays all the fonts in the NavBar a bit thinner than in FireFox, which I can live with (just curious why that might be).

Comment: Glad it helped! As far as I'm aware firefox makes the font more smoother whereas safari and chrome tend to make it more sharper. I haven't come across anything as of yet which will enable you to override these settings.

Comment: Thanks again for the adding info.  I'll post here if I come across more info as well.

Comment: i dont know how you guys got this answer but it should be down below as an answer `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` works like a charm.